# C++ Pass a argument through a class with array index/

Tags: c++, class, parameter-passing

is there anyway I can pass a argument through a class like below for example.

```
class cat
{public:
  void dog(int ID, char *value) // int ID I'd like to be the index array it was called from?
  {
    debug(ID, value);
  }
}

cat cats[18];

cats[1].dog("value second arg, first arg auto filled from index array");
```

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Rephrase, this doesn't make sense to me. as-is

Comment: Why are you naming the class and the method the same thing? That makes it much harder to tell what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to store an INT named ID within the class that is the passed index array.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass a argument through a class"? You may be confused about what the concept of a class is.

Comment: All I am looking to do is pass the first argument of dog from the class array index which in this example is 1.

Comment: would a solution to not automatically fill in the data work for you?  There are really nasty things you could do to get the address of which cat you are.

Comment: Shouldn't the last line be `cats[1].dog(..);` (with s in cats)?

Comment: @ojblass it's just much cleaner the way I'm trying to go with. Why fill in another argument when the index of cats is the same?

Comment: It's *not* cleaner. It's against the normal data flow of C++, and it'd look like weird magic behavior to anyone familiar with the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this out and it worked well:

```
#include <vector>

// Forward declaration of the class
class CatArray;

class Cat {
    // This line means that the CatArray class can 
    // access the private members of this class.
    friend class CatArray;

    private:
        static int ID;

    public:
        void dog(const char* value) {
            // Use ID here any way you want.
        }
};

// Static variables need to be defined.
int Cat::ID = 0;

class CatArray {
    private:
        std::vector<Cat> cats;

    public:
        // explicit means that the argument passed to this constructor must 
        // be an unsigned int. The ": cats(size)" part is an initializer 
        // list that initializes the cats vector so that it would have the 
        // specified size.
        explicit CatArray(unsigned int size) : cats(size) {}

        Cat& operator [](unsigned int index) {
            Cat::ID = index;
            return cats[index];
        }
};
```

Now use it like this:

```
CatArray cats(18);

cats[1].dog("oh lol hi");
```

This method works for any number of arrays you'd wish to declare.

Answer (score 1):

You can use static variable and increment it in constructor, to keep the track of all intances:

```
#include<iostream>


class cat
{
    int ID;
    static int IDTracker;
public:
    cat();
    void dog(char* value);
};

int cat::IDTracker = 0;
cat::cat()
{
    this->ID = cat::IDTracker;
    cat::IDTracker++;
}
void cat::dog(char *value)
{
    std::cout << value << this->ID;
}


int main()
{
    cat cats[18];
    cats[1].dog("Second instance, with index value: ");
    cats[2].dog("Third instance, with index vlaue: ");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really see how this would work, but what I do know is it's illegal to define int's to values in a class.

Comment: i think it would work... static member variables have been supported for a long time...

Comment: also the ID would forget which cat it is.  A member variable should be included for cat that gets assigned the value of the static.

Comment: @ojblass To your first comment: `you didnt new the cats the constructor is not called` - that's **wrong.** `cat cats[18];` allocates and constructs 18 `Cat` objects.

Comment: @vulcanraven I've rolled back your question to its first version. You were misleaded by ojblass' incorrect comment about `new` - your updated code didn't even compile.

Comment: @SergioPotatoNoseAllegretti what you say about initializing `ints` to a value is false in general, but true in the case of a non-const static data member.

Comment: @ojblass To your second comment: indeed, it's not allowed to initialize static class members in line. The correct syntax would be `static int ID;` for declaring the member, then for defining and initializing it outside the class: `int Cat::ID = 0;`

Comment: @H2CO3 are constructors automatically called for the array?

Comment: @ojblass Yes, they are. Why wouldn't they? Just like the constructor is implicitly called when you define an instance of a class like this: `TheClass object;`

Comment: I suppose that is obvious when i stop to think about it.  I haven't coded in c++ for years.  Just getting back into it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure this will work but some variant of it might...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void *foo;

class cat
{
  public:

  void dog(char *value) // int ID I'd like to be the index array it was called from?
  {
    int ID = (this - ((cat *)foo))/(sizeof(cat));
    printf("%d - %s",ID, value);
  }

};


int main ( void )
{
   cat cats[18];
   foo = &(cats);
   cats[1].dog("Fido");
}
```

Comment: I will try in a moment, if it does ill be very happy. I see you understand my question clearly.

Comment: That trow's me 
Exception - iKonroi's DEV (192.168.1.146)
An exception occurred on thread 0xF9000004 "".

 Exception: 0xC0000005
   Address: 0x98022378
Parameters: 0x00000000 0x883A8810 

Access violation reading memory at 0x883A8810.